# update spring security to match url suffix

Tags: spring-security

my spring mvc application uses the following url

```
http://xyz.com/<war name>/springmvc/login
```

I have updated my web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/springmvc/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I updated spring security xml file as follows

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/springmvc/welcome*" access="ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/springmvc/login" default-target-url="/springmvc/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/springmvc/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/springmvc/logout" />
    <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
</http>
```

If i type springmvc/login or springmvc/welcome it goes to login page. but when I enter the username and password, I get a 404. The url changes to http://xyz.com/UserInterface/springmvc/j_spring_security_check. I expect to see hello.jsp as per the controller below

my login controller is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String name = user.getUsername();

    model.addAttribute("username", name);
    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security login + database example");

    //logical view name 
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default login-processing-url property value for form-login is /j_spring_security_check. 
i.e. the login form will be posted to this url.
If you context root is UserInterface the default url would be http://xyz.com/UserInterface/j_spring_security_check, but you are creating the url as http://xyz.com/UserInterface/springmvc/j_spring_security_check which spring-security is not able to understand.

You have two options

1. Change you springSecurityFilterChain url pattern to /* from
   /springmvc/*, and make sure that your custom-login form has action
   as //j_spring_security_check
2. Add custom login-processing-url path in form-login